# Remove all characters from filenames expects first n

Tags: bash, batch-rename

Say I have a list of filenames:

```
gne75943.abc  
njfihf87384758943.abc  
gkjegh689678.abc  
gdreui543843.abc  
gh.abc
```

and I want to get this:

```
gn.abc
nj.abc
gk.abc
gd.abc
gh.abc
```

How would I do this? I can't find anything about this.

Comment: Is it a text file with one filename in each line or do you want to rename the files?

Comment: rename the files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
rename -n 's/(..).*\.abc/$1.abc/' *.abc
```

or

```
for f in *.abc; do echo mv -nv -- "$f" "$(printf '%.2s.abc' "$f")"; done
```

Remove the `echo` / `-n` once you are happy with the indicated replacements